# IE8 background-color rgba

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, rgba

I try to use this code in css to fix opacity background-color in IE8, but it doesn't work.

How can i fix it?

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000,endColorstr=#99000000);
```

The `-ms-` prefix seems unnecessary, and the double quotes look wrong.